# Add a field between name and email

Tags: theming, users

I'm running Drupal 7.39 and I'm trying to add a textfield exactly between the  "name" and "email" field. I also tried with the [`#weight`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#weightval) property as noted by the Form API but it does not work.

Comment: In standard contact form?

Comment: in user-register-form at /admin/people/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing it by custom code, you have to move the field to 'account' container, example code looks like

```
function my_module_name_form_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    // Change weight in respect of user name field.
    $form['field_test']['#weight'] = $form['account']['name']['weight'] + 1;
    // Use machine name of field as form field, replace 'field_test' with your machine name.
    $form['account']['field_test'] = $form['field_test'];
    unset($form['field_test']);
  }
}
```

Comment: nice work arpitr (aka Batman) ! Congrats, it's working. Thank you very much !!
Can you explain me the way you code it please because it still very confusing for me ?
Thank you !

Comment: first thing was to get your field inside the account container as username and email are present in a container rest fields that you add will always remain out of container and weight is relative to container.  Rest in code is just a matter of manipulating form array in a way that we are not messing with form fields(trick of using same machine name)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds). You can create new fields with it and customize the output.

Comment: even with display suite you cannot separate the field "name" and the field "mail".
what i want is something like
name
USERNAME
email

Comment: You are right. I thought, this could be done by ds. Have a look at [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1176568). There is an issue for D8. Looks like no one has a solution for this right now. A dirty solution could be Javascript and/or CSS?

Comment: i can't believe it!